# Deriving equation of ellipse from expanded form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, self-learning, conic-sections

The equation of an ellipse centered around the origin is $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$
The expanded form is $Ax^2 + By^2 + Cx + Dy + E = 0$
How do I derive the second from the first? I have completed the square many times yet I still cannot algebraically manipulate it into the first equation above. I feel hopeless as I am studying mathematics and eventually want to get into higher topics and this simple problem has stumped me :( Thanks!

Comment: Did you collect the $x$-terms together, similarly for the $y$-terms?

Comment: Yes, I did:                                                                                   Ax^2 + Cx + By^2 + Dy = -E                                                                                                 A(x^2 + C/Ax) + B(y^2 + D/By) = -E                                                                   A(x^2 + C/Ax + C/2A^2) + B(y^2 + D/By + D/2B^2) = -E + A(C/2A)^2+B(D/2B)^2                                                                                       A(x+C/2A^2) + B(y+D/2B) = -E + A(C/2A)^2 + B(D/2B)^2 *From here I tried several methods, none worked.

Comment: I apologize for any confusion, I am unsure of how to enter a new line of text.

Comment: There’s something wrong with your last equals sign. My method below differs from yours only in minor details, until just that point. Ask further questions below, too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that if you’re comfortable with completing the square, you shouldn’t have had any difficulty. Here’s how I work:
$$
Ax^2+Cx=A\left(x^2+\frac CAx\right)=A\left(\left(x+\frac C{2A}\right)^2-\frac{C^2}{4A^2}\right)=A\left(x+\frac C{2A}\right)^2-\frac{C^2}{4A}
$$
Do the same thing for the $y$-terms, throw all the constants over onto the righthand side of the equation, and get
$$
A(x-a)^2+B(y-c)^2=\Psi\,,
$$
and then you divide both sides by $\Psi$, take suitable square roots, and there you are.

Comment: Wouldn't C^2/4A^2  be multiplied by A since it is actually distributed? Wouldn't it be -A(C^2/4A^2)?

Comment: @MichaelDuran $-A\times\frac{C^2}{4A^2}=-\frac{C^2}{4A}$